# header (location: someurl.php) not working in online server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

the `header(location: agentverification.php)` does not work when uploaded to godaddy server while it works on localhost server. I've try to edit my codes but the result is still the same. if any of you could help me, I'd appreciate it and thanks in advance.

**agentlogin.php**

```
<form method = "post" action = "agentverification.php" >

<table>

<input type="text" name="ID" size=20 ><br></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Password <font color=red>*</font></td> 

<td><input type="password" name="pass" size=20><br></td></tr>

</table>
<input type = "hidden" name = "login">
<input type = "submit" name = "login" value = "submit" id="pop">
```

**agentverification.php**

```
<?php

session_start();


$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','db5') or die(mysqli_error());

if(isset($_POST['login']))

{
extract($_REQUEST);

$id = $_POST['ID']; 

$pass = $_POST['pass'];


$query= "SELECT * FROM agentReg WHERE AgentID = '$id'";

$record = mysqli_query ($link,$query);


                $check=FALSE;

                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($record))
                {
                    if($id === $row['AgentID']&& $pass === $row['password'] )
                    {
                        $check=TRUE;
                    }
                }


                if($check == TRUE)
                {
                    $_SESSION['AgentID'] = $id;
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
                    header("Location: agentpage.php");
                }
                else 
                { ?> <script> 
                alert ("Wrong combination of ID and Password. Please try again.");
                </script> <?php
                    session_destroy();
                    header("location: agentlogin.php");
                }

}?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

**agentReg** database structure

```
CREATE TABLE agentReg
(AgentID varchar (100) primary key,
password varchar (100));
```

Comment: where you are using header(location: agentverification.php) ?

Comment: I'm going to say that you've already rendered something on the page. Try adopt `ob_start()` and `ob_clean()` for a workaround. (Look in the error log for **Headers already sent** - if it's there, this should solve your problem)

Comment: What's the difference between this and your previous question?

Comment: And again you posted it with horrible formatting.

Comment: Also, it's good practice to `die;` after sending a `header('Location`

Comment: hi @Barmar, instead of you keep questioning my format and my questions, why dont you try to help me? because I can see that you are experienced ,well known to PHP, and supposedly knowledgeable enough to help any people in need here. if i knew the answer, why would i waste my time to post a simple question and hoping for the solutions in here? please understand that im not being rude here. :)

Comment: hi @h. i'll try it in while.

Comment: if you want people to help you, you should do your part and make it easier for them to understand the question. And posting readable code is part of that.

Comment: hi @user1844933, what do you mean where?

Comment: @Barmar, i'll take the best of my situation to post the codes as clear as i could. one question, would you be able to help me?

Comment: sorry @h. actually, in my real code i've put the die; after the header. and now it is working thanks to arnaudrg for answering the question. may god bless all of you.

Comment: So you asked a question without supplying your "real code"? I can now see @Barmar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `header('Location: ...');` after you've printed an output.

In your last `else` you should only include `session_destroy();` and for instance `header('Location: agentlogin.php?error=idpassword');`. The error message should be in `agentlogin.php`.

Comment: Your first line is not entirely true. You can use `ob_start()` and `ob_clean()` to send `header('Location` after output.

Comment: hi there. the code is working just fine now. thanks for answering. may god bless. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

> window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; //Will take you to Google.

Comment: And what if the client has JavaScript disabled?